# Magento 2 - 500 internal server error

Tags: magento-2.0

I have a script which fetches large data from another website using curl.

But after some time I am getting 500 internal server error.
There is nothing wrong in script but the large data is not getting fetched at one time.

I have created Console command also like below

php bin/magento jet:sync_categories

and created necessary files for it.

But from user's perspective its not feasible.

What could be an alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better solution you have to use shell_exec('php your-shell-file &'); Use "&" as last parameter for process your script in background.

Answer (score 0):

For an 500 internal server error; its usually a server side error. If you're working locally, go to your Apache php.ini and change max_execution_time=30 to a largest time frame, let say max_execution_time=300  (Seconds). If you're going to an outsider, that takes time, specially if you're sending big data.

If the problem persist, then change other important values like

```
  memory_limit=2G
  max_execution_time=300  
  post_max_size=8M
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you. 
I am creating extension, so its impossible to inform every user to set this server configuration. Is there any solution that can be managed in coding itself

Comment: I think I'm understading what your doing. Clean your code a little when you go inside a database. A big problem that I usually see in Magento, is that a programmer creates a loop to go inside a database for each SKU. Imagine all the resources that process takes if you have 500 SKUs. For Example. if you have to do a SELECT in the database, instead of doing a loop like foreach($skus as $sku): SELECT * FROM table WHERE sku = "$sku" endforeach. -----> Build the query using IN clause. Like ---> SELECT * FROM table WHERE sku IN $skus.  Those changes are really important.

Comment: If you don't have access to the database, because you're using an API. Set the timeout property to less than 30 seconds, cause usually that's the timeout for a regular server.